# Can't map XF86AudioRaiseVolume key in QJoyPad

Tags: kde, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I wanted to map my PSone gamepad to do some basic KDE/keyboard/mouse functions and everything works well except one thing. I use logitech ultra-x keyboard which has a few multimedia buttons (play, home, volumeup, volumedown..) and I wanted to map <kbd>volumeup</kbd> and <kbd>volumedown</kbd> keys to my pad with everything else.

<kbd>volumedown</kbd> works well, but <kbd>volumeup</kbd> makes some trouble. after I start qjoypad and map it - it does work but after mapping it I still see the "[NO KEY]" (while it is doing its job - volumeup; that's strange).. after I turn qjoypad off and on I get this error: "Error reading button 6" and after that "Error reading definition for joystick 0".

This is my layout:

```
QJoyPad 4.1 Layout File

Joystick 1 {
    Axis 4: gradient, dZone 6505, maxSpeed 11, tCurve 2, sens 2, mouse+h
    Axis 5: gradient, dZone 6264, maxSpeed 11, tCurve 2, mouse+v
    Button 1: key 114
    Button 2: mouse 3
    Button 3: mouse 1
    Button 4: key 113
    Button 5: key 122
    Button 6: key 123
    Button 7: key 62
    Button 8: key 105
    Button 9: key 23
    Button 10: key 65
}
```

With `xev` I got it what 122 and 123 are (they work normaly under KDE when I press them, it's just that 123 wont map and stay mapped for my pad)

```
keycode 122 = XF86AudioLowerVolume
keycode 123 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume
```

Any hint on what I should do to fix this and make my configuration stay? If it means anything, or helps anyhow - system is arch with 2.6.35 kernel, kde 4.5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out how to fix this.  If you download the source code for qjoypad, there should be a file called "constant.h".  In there, there is a variable called "MAXKEY".  The value should be "122", so it just needs to be changed to a higher number (I arbitrarily chose 150).  Safe the file and recompile it.

Be forewarned, though, as I have no idea if this breaks any functionality, but I have not encountered anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a solution, but I know a workaround. Use xmodmap to map 123 to volumeup. Here is the man page: http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xmodmap.1.html

I used xmodmap in the past to map the different, unmapped media buttons on my M$ keyboard.